# sort list of lists in different order based on element

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of lists and wanted to sort this lists based on below order
`date(7th index asc), datetime(6th index asc), type(4th index desc)`

```
from operator import itemgetter

ll = [['2020-02-08', 1, 0, '1001', 'PS', 20, '2021-01-01 10:00:00', '2021-01-01'], 
      ['2020-02-08', 2, 0, '1002', 'VS', 30, '2021-01-01 11:00:00', '2021-01-01']]

sorted_list = sorted(ll, key=itemgetter(7, 6, 4))
print(sorted_list)

output:
[['2020-02-08', 1, 0, '1001', 'PS', 20, '2021-01-01 10:00:00', '2021-01-01'], 
['2020-02-08', 2, 0, '1002', 'VS', 30, '2021-01-01 11:00:00', '2021-01-01']]

but I wanted the output to be in like below
[['2020-02-08', 2, 0, '1002', 'VS', 30, '2021-01-01 11:00:00', '2021-01-01'],
['2020-02-08', 1, 0, '1001', 'PS', 20, '2021-01-01 10:00:00', '2021-01-01']
]
```

I tried using sorted and key itemgetter, but I am unable to specify order for each element.

Any ideas to solve this using sorted or any other approach?

Comment: The output you want doesn't respect the given sorting order, so I'm not really sure what you're looking for.

Comment: I have updated the question with index, for a given date based on timestamp  I will have multiple records hence datetime field.

Comment: @nalanagula if you're using index there is no meaning of ascending and descending. please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

print(sorted(ll, key=lambda x: (datetime.strptime(x[6], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), x[4])))
```